# Atalho terminal MAC/Linux

Tags: terminal, mac

Gente como posso criar um atalho no terminal ? tipo ao inves de digitar `cd xxxx/xxxx/xxxx` eu digitar apenas `goDevWeb` ?
Obrigado

Comment: A sua pergunta não entra no escopo do SOPT, por isso será fechada como descontextualizada, tente ser mais especifico no que pergunta. Veja na [Central de Ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) [Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opa!

É assim:

No seu Mac na pasta usuário abra o arquivo **.bash_profile**. Pode ser no programa em que você programa.

Ele é oculto. Caso seu Finder não mostre os arquivos ocultos digite o seguindo comando no terminal:

`defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true`

Depois disso abra o arquivo **.bash_profile**.

Agora você cria uma função no arquivo:

```
goDevWeb(){
    cd xxx/yyyy/wwwww;
}
```

Depois no terminal na pasta `usuario` digite assim para compilar o arquivo:

`source ~/.bash_profile`.

Depois faça o teste.

Comment: amigo dentro do propio usuario não tem o arquivo, mesmo usando o comando nao aparece....

Comment: Reinicia o Finder. Com o mouse em cima do ícone do Finder na Dock, segura o Option e clica com o botão direito, clique em Reiniciar.

Comment: nem assim... nao exise um comando no terminal que apra direto pelo vim ?

Comment: Que arquivos ocultos que tem na pasta `usuario` ?

Comment: Applications  Movies   composer.phar
Creative Cloud Files Music   https:
Desktop   NetBeansProjects laravel
Documents  Pictures  mcrypt
Downloads  Public   readme.textile
Google Drive  branches  tags
Library   composer.json  trunk

Comment: amigo apos reiniciar o finder novamente surgiuj varios arquivos, mas nenhum com o nome de bash_profile apenas bash_history bash_session

Comment: Tem algum que chama `.profile` ou `.bashrc` ?

Comment: não. Estou usando a nova versao do mac a que saiu por ultimo ....

Comment: Lista atualizado dos arquivos ao usar ls -a : .   .netbeans-derby  Movies
..   .oracle_jre_usage Music
.CFUserTextEncoding .p2   NetBeansProjects
.DS_Store  .putty   Pictures
.Trash   .ssh   Public
.WebIde100  .subversion  branches
.WebStorm10  .svn   composer.json
.WebStorm11  .viminfo  composer.phar
.android  Applications  https:
.bash_history  Creative Cloud Files laravel
.bash_sessions  Desktop   mcrypt
.composer  Documents  readme.textile
.config   Downloads  tags
.eclipse  Google Drive  trunk
.gradle   Library

Comment: Então cria um arquivo `.bash_profile` e faça isso que te falei.

Comment: deu cert... obrigadoooo